# Insert into Hive struct column by spilitting hive columns from other table

Tags: select, struct, insert, hive

I have the below requirement that i want to achieve using Hive.

1. Table A with Struct 1 column.
2. Create Table B to split Table A's Struct columns and load as 2 different columns.

Below is the DDL and the steps that i have tried.

**Table A :**

cluster                 string                  from deserializer
schema                  string                  from deserializer
table                   string                  from deserializer
primarykey              struct  from deserializer
data                    struct    from deserializer
deleted                 boolean                 from deserializer
truncate                boolean                 from deserializer
version                 bigint                  from deserializer

**Table B :**
user_id                 string                  from deserializer
shippingattr            struct
billingattr             struct

i have tried the following.

```
insert into Table B
(
user_id,
shippingattr.username,
shippingattr.shipping_fname,
shippingattr.shipping_lname,
shippingattr.shipping_address,
shippingattr.shipping_address2,
shippingattr.shipping_city,
shippingattr.shipping_state,
shippingattr.shipping_zip,
shippingattr.phone,
billingattr.billing_is_shipping,
billingattr.billing_fname,
billingattr.billing_lname,
billingattr.billing_address,
billingattr.billing_address2,
billingattr.billing_city,
billingattr.billing_state,
billingattr.billing_zip
)

select 
primarykey.user_id,
data.username,
data.shipping_fname,
data.shipping_lname,
data.shipping_address,
data.shipping_address2,
data.shipping_city,
data.shipping_state,
data.shipping_zip,
data.phone,
data.billing_is_shipping,
data.billing_fname,
data.billing_lname,
data.billing_address,
data.billing_address2,
data.billing_city,
data.billing_state,
data.billing_zip
from Table A;
```

but this errors out., could you please let me know the right way to insert this data.

**Error Message :** 
    NoViableAltException(284@[])
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectClause(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectClause(HiveParser.java:40147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.singleSelectStatement(HiveParser.java:38048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectStatement(HiveParser.java:37754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:37654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:36898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:36774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1040)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:636)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:50 cannot recognize input near '(' 'user_id' ',' in select clause

Comment: show us the error.

Comment: @strugee, updated with the error message. Not sure if this is the right way to insert into a struct data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions, I have implemented it this way.

insert into table Table B select user_id,
named_struct('username',Table2.data.username,'shipping_fname',Table2.data.shipping_fname,......) as shippingattr,
named_struct('billing_is_shipping',Table2.data.billing_is_shipping,.....,'billing_zip',Table2.data.billing_zip) as billingattr
from Table A;

Thanks & Regards,
Srivignesh KN

Answer (score 0):

For start, Hive does not except a list of columns for insert.
All columns should be inserted, by their order.

```
insert into Table B
select ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Above Scenario canbe handled as below. Sample example to insert data in struct:-

```
create table xyz (a STRUCT<x : int , y :String , z:int , zz : int >, b string );

 insert into table xyz select named_STRUCT(x,12,y,'text',z,2,zz,3) , 'text' from dummy limit 1;

 create table xyz1 (a1 STRUCT<x : int , y :String > , a2 struct<z:int , zz : int> , b String);

 insert into table xyz1  select named_struct('x',a.x,'y',a.y) ,named_struct('z',a.z,'zz',a.zz) ,b from xyz;

insert into table xyz1(a1,a2,b)  select named_struct('x',a.x,'y',a.y) ,named_struct('z',a.z,'zz',a.zz) , b from xyz;
```